# Почему return возвращает None?

Tags: python, list

Сталкивался уже не раз с этим, но до сих пор не могу понять, почему так происходит. Условно есть какой-то класс колоды, в нем метод генерирует колоду карт и с помощью рандома ее тасует с помощью `random.shuffle`. Если создавать список и сразу передавать его в функцию, то вернется None, но если сначала создать список и записать в него результат, потом перетасовать и вернуть, то все отлично. По сути и в том, и в том случае передается список, почему так происходит? Для наглядности приведу пример.

```
return random.shuffle([f'{i}:{j}' for i in Deck.SUIT_LIST for j in Deck.RANK_LIST_RUSSIAN])

rus_deck = [f'{i}:{j}' for i in Deck.SUIT_LIST for j in Deck.RANK_LIST_RUSSIAN]
random.shuffle(rus_deck)
return rus_deck
```

В первом случае выводит None, во втором нужный результат.

Comment: «почему так происходит?» — потому что функция shuffle ничего не возвращает

Comment: Точнее, возвращает None. И именно это в свою очередь возвращает return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `random.shuffle` перемешивает список "на месте", т. е. изменяет существующий, а не создает и возвращает новый. А в Python'е, если функция ничего возвращать не должна, она возвращает `None`.

[Документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

> random.shuffle(x)
>
> Shuffle the sequence `x` in place.

перевод:

> random.shuffle(x)
>
> Перемешивает последовательность `x` *на месте*.

Comment: Зачем-же отвечать на дубликаты?

Comment: @чистов_n, тогда я не знал, что это дубликат... вопрос-то закрыт 19 часов назад, а мой ответ - 21 час назад.